# Can a Magus not recharge spellstrike while in arcane cascade?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, magus

I'm new to Pathfinder (2e) in general and I wish to understand the magus class more.

So the magus spellstrike has a recharge mechanic before you can use it again, according the the action's definition this recharge action has the *concentrate* trait.

> After you use Spellstrike, you can't do so again until you recharge
> your Spellstrike as a single action, which has the concentrate trait.
> You also recharge your Spellstrike when you cast a conflux spell that
> takes at least 1 action to cast; casting a focus spell of another type
> doesn't recharge your Spellstrike.

According to the tags of the Arcane Cascade feature, it also has the *concentrate* trait.

Does that mean the magus cannot use the recharge action while in Arcane Cascade?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### They can

Not being able to use two Concentrate effects is a D&D 5e thing, and there is no such rule in Pathfinder 2e. [Concentrate](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=32) is just a trait with no inherent mechanical effect.

> An action with this trait requires a degree of mental concentration and discipline.

Other effects might reference Concentrate trait, such as Barbarians' [Rage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=3) or Fighters' [Disruptive Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=401) feat.